# What all files do we need to include in our JSP of ExtJS 5 for creating a page?

Tags: file, jsp, import, include, extjs5

I am trying to work with ExtJS 5. I need to know which all files need to be imported in JSP/HTML page from EXT package.

Comment: It would depend on what the page is doing. You should look at the docs for extjs5 and use import what is relevant to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
            href="http://**yourdomainorlocalhost**/ext-5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-
crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://**yourdomainorlocalhost**/ext-5.0.0/build/bootstrap.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I will provide 2 answers to your question:
If you are using Sencha Cmd and the bootstrapping that it provides to generate your application your index.html could look as simple as the following for the basic application in the Sencha theming guide: (Since all the work is done by the microloader and all the files that you mention in index.html now sit in a file call app.json.) 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/theming.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>ThemeDemoApp</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The second application is a basic Hello World including ExtJS 5 library in your application without the bootstrap:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Hello Ext JS 5</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.0.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.0.0/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following Files:
-ext-all-debug.js or ext-all.js 
-extext-*-all.css
and 
-viewport.js [This file contains Ext.application related defination]